# How to filter rows by Max value grouped by 2 columns in google sheets?

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to filter to rows that have a max date value and grouped by Name in google sheets for example

```
Data: 
Date          Name      Number 
6/30/2017     John      1 
7/1/2017      John      2 
7/1/2017      Jane      4 
7/2/2017      Jane      3

Desired Output: 
Date       Name     Number 
7/1/2017   John     2 
7/2/2017   Jane     3
```

Any Help would be gladly apprciated!!!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `Date` is in A1, stolen (but adapted!) from [Ed Nelson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2040491/ed-nelson) and UNTESTED:

```
=FILTER(A$1:C$5,MMULT((A$1:A$5>TRANSPOSE(A$1:A$5))*(B$1:B$5=TRANSPOSE(B$1:B$5)),SIGN(ROW(B$1:B$5)))<>0)
```